# Concatenate multiple data from XML to web form using Selenium IDE

Tags: xml, selenium, ide, concatenation

I have from the XML file the following data:
`DOBDD="21" DOBMM="07" DOBYYYY="1987"`

I need to input all these data into one field into a website:
`Date of Birth: 21-07-1987`

I used the following command in Selenium IDE:

```
Command: type
Target: formData.dateofbirth
Value: ${DOBDD}&"-"&${DOBMM}&"-"&${DOBYYYY}
```

XML:

```
<testdata> 
<test Email="myname@email.com" MobileNo="0400000000" Title="Mr" GivenNames="Eban" Surname="Ster" DOBDD="21" DOBMM="07" DOBYYYY="1987" ResAddress1="3 Street" ResSuburbTown="Sydney" ResState="New South Wales" ResPC="2000" /> 
</testdata>
```

However, only 21-07 appears. Doesn't include the 2nd hyphen and the year.

Comment: Please post the relevant XML.

Comment: <testdata>
 <test Email="myname@email.com" MobileNo="0400000000"  Title="Mr" GivenNames="Eban" Surname="Ster" DOBDD="21" DOBMM="07" DOBYYYY="1987" ResAddress1="3 Street"  ResSuburbTown="Sydney" ResState="New South Wales" ResPC="2000" />
</testdata>

Comment: Please edit the question, add the XML, and properly format it. It will help others attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on

> Selenium IDE : 2.9.1.1 -signed
>   Selblocks : 2.1.1 - signed
>   Firefox : 47.0

There is no need for `&"-"&` to add hyphen.
You can simply use

> ${DOBDD}-${DOBMM}-${DOBYYYY}

And are you sure you can use `<test>` as the tagName in the xml.
I have used `<vars>` instead of `<test>` in the following way

```
<testdata> 
<vars Email="myname@email.com" MobileNo="0400000000" Title="Mr" GivenNames="Eban" Surname="Ster" DOBDD="21" DOBMM="07" DOBYYYY="1987" ResAddress1="3 Street" ResSuburbTown="Sydney" ResState="New South Wales" ResPC="2000" /> 
</testdata>
```